# How can I integrate a poll module into a Grails application?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In my Grails application, I would like to integrate a simple poll module through which people can vote (without authentication), with different options, integrated into the homepage of my website. Poll Results (preferably graphical) can be shown in a different page (or in the same module frame).

Is there a Grails plugin or any other simple way to integrate such a feature in my website?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but it seems like [grailspodcast.com](http://grailspodcast.com) uses some external web service called twiigs. Grailspodcast is open source so you may take a peek how it's done if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck man.  You could easily build such functionality and create your own plugin though...